# Update statement in java

Tags: java

*Hi all,*
This is my code,

```java
public static boolean updateDB() {
  Connection cn = null; 
  PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  boolean result = false;   
  int number; 
  String insetSQL ="update quan set ten_quan='lin' where id=1"; 
  try {
    cn = LocalDatabasePooling.getInstance().getConnection();
    pstmt = cn.prepareStatement(insetSQL);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
    result = true;
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    if (rs != null) {
      try {
        rs.close();
      } catch (SQLException sqle) { }
    }
    if (pstmt != null) {
      try {
        pstmt.close();
      }
      catch (SQLException sqle) { }
    }
    if (cn1 != null) {
      try {
        cn1.close();
      }
      catch (SQLException sqle) { }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Is the code above correct? But when I debug, I saw that the line

```
number = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

was not executed and the code below it were not executed too.

when I add watch

```
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

I saw this info

> error(during the evaluation

What is wrong?

Comment: Why did you change/fix the code in the question without leaving feedback on my answer? Now my answer makes very little sense to ones who haven't read the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently an exception was been thrown which was completely ignored by your code. Something like:

```
try {
    // Your code was here.
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // But you didn't put anything here.
}
```

You should at least log/print the stacktrace

```
try {
    // Your code was here.
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or, even better, just throw it.

```
public SomeObject someMethod() throws SQLException {
    try {
        // Your code was here.
    } finally {
        // Surely close resources here.
    }
}
```

Exceptions contain a wealth of information about the cause of the problem and they should not be ignored, unless you really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

pstmt.executeUpdate(); not executed - That is OK. But what are you getting ? A exception trace in the command line ? Try to add try catch block as mentioned BalusC and run the problem again. There may be problem with your sql , like table not exist , column name is incorrect or your datasouce hasn't return the connection at all. you might get a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put ? in the statement, then insert the values into the preparedStatement.

If it is a simple "straight" SQL you want to execute, there is no need for using a PreparedStatement